# Selenium Error: StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

If you see the attached image I need to flip that switch as I do not want this system to run under my name but under the systems name. I need to click on this toggle to switch to run as system mode. I am getting an error StaleElementReferenceException and when I did some research I needed to import NoSuchElementException and StaleElementReferenceException and than assign it to igonered_exception and then call this variable in intialize it in the webdriverwait function of the run_as_button variable...when I did this I still got the error.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3oxQ.png)

Below you will find the relevant code in python which includes the imports and the lines of code that is causing this error

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#ignore exception
igonered_exception = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)

#run as system
run_as_button = WebDriverWait(driver,120,ignored_exceptions=igonered_exception).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,('//*[@id="core-page main"]/div[2]/div/lp-section/section/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/lp-slide-toggle/div'))))
action.move_to_element(run_as_button).click(run_as_button).perform()
```

Below is a snip of the HTML CODE for the toggle switch

```
<div _ngcontent-qyq-c18="" class="row">
   <div _ngcontent-qyq-c18="" class="col col-md-3"></div>
   <div _ngcontent-qyq-c18="" class="col-12 col-md-2 d-flex align-items-center"><label _ngcontent-qyq-c18="">Run as System</label></div>
   <div _ngcontent-qyq-c18="" class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <lp-slide-toggle _ngcontent-qyq-c18="" _nghost-qyq-c10="">
         <div _ngcontent-qyq-c10="" class="slide-toggle">
            <input _ngcontent-qyq-c10="" type="checkbox" id="kl-toggle-1611252633257330581">
            <label _ngcontent-qyq-c10="" for="kl-toggle-1611252633257330581">
               <div _ngcontent-qyq-c10="">
                  <!---->
               </div>
               <div _ngcontent-qyq-c10="">
                  <!---->
               </div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </lp-slide-toggle>
   </div>
   <div _ngcontent-qyq-c18="" class="col col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

Below you will find the entire output of the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/patel/Desktop/Python/Automation/import_file.py", line 59, in <module>
    action.move_to_element(run_as_button).click(run_as_button).perform()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
    self.w3c_actions.perform()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\actions\action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
    self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: "lp-slide-toggle" is not valid HTML... which means that's used as a placeholder and is replaced once the script hits it.  That causes the stale element exception.  Load the page, and then inspect the element you want to target.  (right-click, choose "inspect")  It also helps to watch the inspector while manually clicking... the element the handler is attached to should flash...  also, there is no need to add ignored exceptions... webdriverwait already includes the proper ones.

Comment: @pcalkins so i updated that line to the below and I still get stale element exception run_as_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,('//*[@id="core-page main"]/div[2]/div/lp-section/section/div/div/div[2]/div[3]'))))

Comment: "lp-section" is also a placeholder... Inspect your target and post that markup here.  (right-click the node to copy to clipboard) you should really simplify your xpaths to target what you want.   (though that's not causing your particular problem here, path based xpaths are "brittle".. instead use the "id" of the tag if available. ex: //input[@id='kl-toggle-1611252633257330581']

Comment: to be clear what is happening is that your webddriverwait is waiting only until it finds this specific tag... which is a placeholder to be written over later via javascript.  (The page might be lazy-loading or something like that...)  It then gets written over before you call your action on that element reference so it's "stale".  (it no longer exists, or the DOM has been updated so the pointer is pointing incorrectly)

Comment: @pcalkins i wanted to use the kl-toggle-1611252633257330581 but the number after toggle- is always changing after each instance

Comment: it's possible that //input[contains(@id, "kl-toggle-")] would be enough.  If not mix in just enough path-based stuff to target.